# Why the zsh codes like [ $var == 'str' ] runs well as a command but error as a script file?

Tags: shell, zsh

The `zsh_test.sh` is simple, as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

if [ $USER == 'root' ]; then
    echo "root"
else
    echo "not root"
fi
```

- Copy and paste the above codes into a zsh shell, it executed well.

  ```
  $ #!/usr/bin/env zsh
  $ if [ $USER == 'root' ]; then
  then>     echo "root"
  then> else
  else>     echo "not root"
  else> fi                     
  not root
  ```
- But directly execute script file `zsh_test.sh`, got an error.

  ```
  $ ./zsh_test.sh
  ./zsh_test.sh:3: = not found
  ```

Comment: The error message does not come from the script which you posted. For debugging, run this script with `zsh -x ./zsh_test.sh`.

Comment: Don't post this in a comment! This is virtually unreaadable. Amend your question by providing tis information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now see what's wrong: You are the victim of a fairly obscure zsh mechanism, which is described in the *zshexpn* man page and is called *'=' expansion*. From the man-page:

> If  a  word  begins with an unquoted `=' and the EQUALS option is set, the remainder of the word is taken as the name of a command.  If a command exists by that name, the word is  replaced by the full pathname of the command.

You can try it with the command

```
echo ==
```

which also outputs this error message. For instance, on my platofm

```
echo =ruby
```

outputs `/usr/bin/ruby`, because this is where I have ruby installed. If you would have in your PATH a program named `=`, the `==` would resolve to this path.

While it is unusual to use a double `==` sign inside `[ ... ]`, the zsh implementation of this command allows it, but you would have to quote the operator, to avoid =-expansion:

```
if [ $USER '==' root ]; then
```

An alternative would be to use `[[ ... ]]` instead. This is not a command, but a syntactic construct, and expansion rules are different inside it. Therefore

```
if [[ $USER == root ]]; then
```

would work as well.

Comment:  Add a little info, `setopt noequals` will disable `=` expansion. And `setopt nonomatch` will just keep the code when an expansion error occurred instead of return a "not found" error. Thank you!

Comment: @SanXell : Right, but don't forget that `nonomatch` is dangerous: It not only supresses the error message with =-expansion, but also for filename expansion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you are using test command wrong. Let's see why.

`test` command is defined since Unix version III. You can often find this command also as `[` binary in your PATH. In most modern shells (let's pretend that bash is modern shell as well), there is also implementation of `test` or `[` as builtin command. From the specification, the only valid way to compare two strings is this:

```
       STRING1 = STRING2
              the strings are equal

       STRING1 != STRING2
              the strings are not equal
```

Original strict POSIX implementation of test command is somehow limited and can be difficult to use. But it is portable, and that it's main strength. But what if you don't care about portability at all? Then there are *Conditional Expressions*.

*Conditional Expressions*, available as `[[` builtin command, are improved, not POSIX compatible replacement for original test command. Look in [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html) for the things you can compare with them to get the idea. Double equality sign (==) is also supported (and the documentation explicitly says it's for compatibility with other sorts of computer language.)

## Conclusion?

When you are writing scripts for particular shell, like zsh, and you are absolutely sure that portability is not important for you, always use `[[` instead of `[`. Your life will be easier and change to your script is minimal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

if [[ $USER == 'root' ]]; then
    echo "root"
else
    echo "not root"
fi
```

If portability between different shells and environments is necessary, you will have to use original `test` or `[` command, and forget about zsh, `==` and many other things at all.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$USER" = 'root' ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "root"
else
    printf '%s\n' "not root"
fi
```

Comment: Nice explanation. But I would like to know why the behavior described in the problem occurs internally in zsh? Intuitively, if the code can be executed successfully as a command, then putting it in the script file should also be able to execute successfully instead of reporting an error.

Comment: default zsh behaviour is error. I'm sure it must be something in your .zshrc which alters interactive session. I did quick testing and found out I can replicate it with `setopt noequals`. Then zsh's builtin `[` is able to parse == but this is something I would strongly disencourage. Check output of your `setopts`.

Comment: @rcwnd_cz: Your explanation would be correct for, say, bash or sh, but not for zsh. For instance, while `[[ a == a]]` outputs _zsh: = not found_,  `[ a '==' a ] && echo x` works well.

Comment: @rcwnd_cz: Great, your idea is correct. In my environment `setopt nonomatch` cause the behavior described in the problem. And I tested `setopt noequals` too, same as your result. Thank you!